# django flatpages vs. named url's reverse

Tags: python, django

I am trying to set up flatpages for my django project. everything works fine. except this guy:

I have urls like:

```
url(r'^terms/$', TemplateView.as_view(template_name='terms.html'),
                       name='terms'),
```

which goes to a static html file. and in template i have:

```
<a href="{% url 'terms' %}">terms</a>
```

now I set up a new flatpage for terms page. Now I want to break the old static url `terms` (so that 404 get raised) so that my new flatpage will be found. my flatpages slug is also `/terms/`.

How can I "remove" the old slug so that my flatpage will be called?

.. i mean, without changing `{% url 'terms '%}`

Comment: Guten tag! Haben Sie entfernt den Datenbankeintrag für "terms" ? Once you remove the record, your pattern work.

Comment: @Brandon danke Herr Taylor ;)

Comment: Bitte! Always glad to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the url to a single flatpage in your `urls.py`. In your case, all you need is:

```
url(r'^terms/$', 'django.contrib.flatpages.views.flatpage', {'url': '/terms/'}, name='terms')
```

See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/flatpages/#using-the-urlconf